# ActiveDocument.Tables(k).Range.Cells(j).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor returns -1

Tags: vba, colors, ms-word, ms-office

I have a Word 2007 doc with a lot of tables. Each table has certain cells filled with 2 custom colors. I created a macro which takes for input 3 values to feed the RGB function, creating one of the colors, matches it against each of the colors, and changes the match with a new color.

I used an `If` statement that compares the color of the filled cell with the color returned by the RGB function, feeding the function with the input given by the user.

```
If ActiveDocument.Tables(k).Range.Cells(j).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(inputRed, inputGreen, inputBlue) Then
       'code
end if
```

As I was looking through the document to see the results, I noticed that a few cells from 3 tables were left with the old color, so apparently the macro could not recognize it.

In Word 2007 I selected the cell that was supposed to have its color changed. I went to *Home -> Shading -> More colors -> Custom* and saw the 3 values that matched perfectly with the 3 values given as input by the user.

After 30 minutes of staring at the monitor, I thought about going to the doctor to have my eyes examined. :)

Before doing that though, I started to debug the app. on each of the cells that were not changed. Upon examining this line:
`ActiveDocument.Tables(k).Range.Cells(j).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor`
I saw that it returned **-1**.

I am thinking -1 is the equivalent of null or nil, meaning that either the cell is not filled, but if so, why can I see the RGB values?  Or perhaps the system can't read the RGB values, but who is this system exactly?

Do you have a link where the `Shading.BackgroundPatternColor` method is well explained?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a value of -1, but colours in Word 2007 changed slightly so that the values were no longer necessarily RGB values. I have written extensively on this - please see http://www.wordarticles.com/Articles/Colours/2007.php

Comment: Thx a lot Tony

I shall read your post, it's quite long :) , and come back with a comment as soon as possible.